# python list creator greater than

Tags: python

You will be creating the method sum_firsts which will accept a list of numbers as a parameter, and will return the sum of all values greater than the first value.  Call your method from the main method and print its results.  Your method sum_firsts should not do any printing.

```
Sample Data:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       --> sum is 14
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]       --> sum is 0
[5, 3, 7, 4, 9, 1, 0] --> sum is 16
```

```
def sum_firsts():
  Numbers = input("Enter Numbers:")
  list1 = []
  list1.extend([Numbers])
  list1.sort()
  for x in range (1,len(list1)):
    sum += list1[x]
  return sum

def main():
  sum_firsts()
  print(sum)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 19, in <module>
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sum'
```

This is the error message i get. I am not sure how to get the variable sum to be used in the main method

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable `sum`. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print sum, you would need

```
sum = sum_firsts()
print(sum)
```

With the error you are getting, you want to globalize the variable sum

```
def sum_firsts()
    global sum
```

Comment: It still says that sum is used before its assigned

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

`input(...)` returns a string. You need to convert them to integers.

If your input is space separated integers then try this.

```
data=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

```
data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
total_sum=sum(i for i in data[1:] if i>data[0])
```

---

Validation

```
>>> data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sum(i for i in data[1:] if i>data[0])
14
>>> data=[5,4,3,2,1]
>>> sum(i for i in data[1:] if i>data[0])
0
>>> data=[5, 3, 7, 4, 9, 1, 0]
>>> sum(i for i in data[1:] if i>data[0])
16
```

**Note:** Never use keywords/Built-ins as variable names. You are using `sum` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. Thank you for the help. I modified some of the requirements. As i do this in REPL it does not pass the tests but passes it when i do it manually.

```
def sum_firsts():
  #Numbers = input("Enter Numbers:")
  list1 = [5,3,7,4,9,1,0]
  #list1.extend([Numbers])
  #list1.sort()
  sum = 0

  for x in range (1,len(list1)):
    if (list1[0] < list1[x]):
      sum += list1[x]
  return sum

def main():
  sum = sum_firsts()
  print(sum)
####################################
### Do not edit below this line. ###
####################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: id recommend going over some python basics as well. bring up some questions in your head and just play around with the language.